# Rows are not insert in windows form datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datatable

I want to insert data grid using datatable and define the grid columns in a program. Please help me what`s wrong with this code???
Following error is occur "Unable to cast object of type System.String to type System.String[]"

```
 enter code here 
SqlConnection connection;
    string query;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dRows;
    public void ViewGrid()
    {
    connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            query = @"SELECT * FROM TBLWorkers";
            //cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Workers");

            int MaxRows = ds.Tables["Workers"].Rows.Count;

            label1.Text = MaxRows.ToString();

            dRows = ds.Tables["Workers"].Rows[0];


            // Create an unbound DataGridView by declaring a column count.
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;

            // Set the column header names.
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Recipe";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Category";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Main Ingredients";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Rating";

            object[] rows1 = new object[] { dRows[0].ToString(), dRows[1], dRows[2], dRows[3] };
            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please accept some of your existing answered questions if any of the given answers, answered the question!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that rowArray is a string not a string[].

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through an `object[]` and treating the elements in that array as `string[]` and element 0 of that array is definitely a `string` and not a `string[]`.

I *think* what you intend to do, based on what you've written, is insert a single row into the DataGridView, because that's all dRows holds is one table row.  You're code is partially from the MSDN example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx) and if you look at how that example works, you'll see that they build up a bunch of `string[]` to add *unbound* rows to the DataGridView.

Is that what you want to do here?  Add an unbound row?  You've already got a `DataTable`.  You could just use data binding to solve this rather than retrieving the data from the DB, then copying it into an `object[]` just to turn around and put it into an unbound DataGridView.

You could just do this:

```
string[] myRow = new string[] { dRows[0].ToString(), dRows[1].ToString(), dRows[2].ToString(), dRows[3].ToString() };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(myRow);
```

and I think that would work.  Didn't test it, but I think that'll do it.  But I'd probably set up the data binding if I were doing it.